# C#アプリケーション　.NET Framework 4.0と4.5.2以降の互換性

Tags: c#, .net

タイトルの件、.NET 4.0向けにコンパイルしたアプリケーションをそのまま
.NET 4.5.2以降のランタイム環境で動作させる場合に
互換性の問題で動作しないということはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このサイトで移行元/移行先の版数を指定して調べられるようです。
`FROM .NET FRAMEWORK VERSION`と`TO .NET FRAMEWORK VERSION`の両方をドロップダウンリストボックスで指定できます。`4.8`はまだ日本語化が追い付いていないようですが。

[.NET Framework 4.0 から 4.5.2 への移行に関するランタイム変更](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.5.2)

それぞれ、結構な量の記述があります。
該当するものがあれば、動作しないとか、動作が違うとか、あるでしょう。

---

ちなみに、移行先を最新版である`4.8`に指定すると以下になります。
回答時点では英語のままです。

[Runtime Changes for Migration from .NET Framework 4.0 to 4.8](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.8)

現時点で 4.0 -> 4.8 の予想影響度別で数えると、以下になります。

- メジャー : 9件
  多数のアプリに影響するか、またはコードに重大な変更を加える必要のある重要な変更点
- マイナー : 42件
  少数のアプリに影響するか、またはコードにわずかな変更を加える必要のある変更点
- エッジ ケース : 51件
  一般的ではない特定のシナリオでアプリに影響する変更点
- 透過的 : 4件
  アプリの開発者やユーザーには大きな影響を及ぼさない変更点
  アプリはこの変更のために変更を加える必要は無い

Comment: 4.5.2以降、つまり4.8環境でも実行される可能性があるため、比較すべきは4.0から4.8にするべきではないでしょうか？

Comment: それも紹介したページで移行先を変更指定すれば出てきます。ただ、書いたように4.8はまだ英語記述のままです。

Comment: そうではなく、この回答では4.0～4.5.2の差分を確認することで4.5.2以降（例えば4.8）の互換性の確認が済むかのような誤解を与えるのでは？、という指摘です。

Comment: 紹介先を見れば、自分で工夫出来ると思うのですが、まあ追記しておきます。